# Python not able to show output for few libraries

Tags: python-2.7, fedora-21

I'm running the code below. From terminal I'm putting `python test.py`. But it's giving me nothing.

```
###test.py### Version 2
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print "Hello"

t=Timer(5, hello)
t.start()
```

I tried the same code in a different machine, it's showing me the output properly. I tried going step by step. I kept only the `print` statement and it's working fine. Then I added that print to a function, and called the function, it is also working fine. As soon as I add the `Timer`, the python command keeps on running without showing any output, until I stop it by force.

Previously the same thing happened with `scapy` library. But after a system restart it worked fine. But now it is not working after the system restart also.

What could be the problem?

**Note 1:** 6 days back, it was not behaving like this. Is there any chance of any malwares?

**Note 2:** A peculiar behaviour.

```
###test.py### Version 1

from threading import Timer
from time import sleep

def hello():
    print "Hello"

t=Timer(5, hello)
t.start()
sleep(10)
```

This was my version 1. After it didn't work, I modified it to Version 2 which is mentioned above. Still no output. But when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, It's showing

```
  from time import sleep as _sleep
 File .........., line 2, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Though that line of code is not present there. I rechecked the saved file whether I saved or not. I also checked whether any `pyc` file is creating trouble or not. But no `pyc` was there.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned the Python version and platform (distro and version, not just "linux").

Comment: Just to make sure: Is this the Python 2.7 that comes with Fedora (or that's part of the core repo, if 21 has make 2.7 an optional install already)?

Comment: No. it's the one that comes with Fedora.

Comment: Do you have a file named either `time.py` or `threading.py` (or, did you used to have one, and still have `time.pyc` or `threading.pyc`) in the same directory as `test.py`, or anywhere else on your `sys.path`?

Comment: I did a `rm *.pyc`. But there was no `pyc` files in that directory. Recently I've not installed any application or modified `sys.path`. So I guess, it is intact. It's not only with `threading` or `time`. With `scapy` also it behaves the same.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm sure `scapy` uses `time`. Again, check whether there's a file named `time.py` in the current directory. Or look at the answer I just added for a simple foolproof test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file named `time.py` in the same directory as `test.py`. (Or you did have one, and still have `time.pyc`. Or you have some somewhere else in your `sys.path` for some reason.)

When you do `import time` or `from time import sleep`, it's not opening the stdlib's `time`, it's opening your `time.py`.

And even if you don't do that, inside [`threading`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py):<sup>*</sup>

```
from time import time as _time, sleep as _sleep
```

So, if your `time.py` doesn't have a `sleep` method, this will just raise an exception. But if it *does*, that's when things get fun. Everything will seem to work fine, until the [`Timer`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py#l1046) thread sleeps for 5 seconds by (ultimately) calling a block-and-spin loop inside [`Condition.wait`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py#l309). If your `time.sleep` function isn't actually sleeping, or if it multiplies the sleep time by 1000, or whatever, that could cause it to burn up 100% CPU busy-waiting, or to take much longer than 5 seconds to fire, or who knows what.

Likewise, `scapy` is almost certainly using the `time` module, which is why it's having the same problem.

---

At any rate, you can test this pretty easily:

```
$ python2.7
>>> import time
>>> time.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
>>> import threading
>>> threading.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc
```

If the results aren't similar to that, there's your problem.

---

<sub>* The copy of 2.7.6 I have lying around is slightly different, but I assume Fedora 21 will be closer to the latest 2.7 trunk than 2.7.6, so that's what I linked to… At any rate, the differences don't matter.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. There was a trace of `time.pyc`. I deleted that. and it worked fine. Quick question. `import time` or `from time import sleep` were not there, still why it was trying to import them? is it due to the `Timer`?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't document anywhere what happens if the main thread exits while non-daemon background threads are running. In practice, at least CPython implicitly `join`s them at some point—but it may do some cleanup first. Which could possibly involve closing `sys.stdout`.<sup>*</sup>

In fact, if you look at [the 2.7 source for `threading`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py#l792), it explicitly stashes `stderr` at launch specifically to make sure it can still print exception tracebacks if the main thread has already closed `sys.stderr`.

So, what you're trying to do isn't supposed to work reliably. If you want to make sure absolutely background threads (including those running `Timer`s) have full access to all the normal runtime stuff, you need to keep the main thread running—usually by `join`ing them. (Yes, you can call `join` on a `Timer`; as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) say, "`Timer` is a subclass of `Thread`.")

---

<sub>* The details of where and how this happens have changed multiple times, and I don't remember exactly how 2.7 did it. Originally it was just a `__del__` method on a special `_MainThread` object that gets created to represent the main thread as soon as any other thread is started, but later there was an atexit handler, then special support to call `threading._shutdown` if it exists, then it was changed again to fit the module-unloading fixes…</sub>

Comment: with `join` also it's not working. I tried with `time.sleep(10)` in the main thread too. No result.

Comment: @RatDon: Just to take rule out anything funky with `Timer`, can you just `def hello(): time.sleep(5); print 'Hello'` then create a `threading.Thread(target=hello)` instead of a `threading.Timer`? It _should_ have exactly the same effect, but… let's see if it does.

Comment: @RatDon: Also, try replacing the `print 'Hello'` with `raise Exception('Does my traceback get printed?')`.

Comment: @RatDon: One last thing: with both `t.join()` and `time.sleep(10)` in the main thread, if you put a `print 'Main thread done waiting" right after that, does it get printed?

Comment: Updated the question with some of my observation. Have a look at it. I'll test whatever you said and will update it.